# LINQ - List within a List filtering

Tags: .net, linq, list, lambda

I have those classes:

```
public class Flight
{
    public string FlightNum { get; set; }
    public List<Pax> Pax { get; set; }
}

public class Pax
{
    public string PaxName { get; set; }
    public string PaxSurName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to filter flight so that it will only contain flights whose passenger's name is a certain *string* 
I tried:

```
var paxList = flights.Where(f => f.Pax.Where(p => p.PaxName == "d"));
```

The above code didn't work...
e.g: I want to this in a SINGLE Lambda expression

Comment: of course it won't work, Where takes a Func that returns bool, but Where itself returns a new IEnumerable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Where` needs a function that returns a `boolean`.

```
var paxList = flights.Where(f => f.Pax.Any(p => p.PaxName == "d"));
```

The nested expression `f.Pax.Any(p => p.PaxName == "d")` will return true if *any* `p` matches the criterion that `PaxName` is exactly `"d"`.

And hence the resulting list will be of flights (not passengers) which contain any passenger meeting that criterion. I mention this because `paxList` is potentially not a good variable name.

Comment: or .All() if all the PaxName's needs to be "d"

Comment: @Pauli - would be a pretty weird flight! Everyone flying to a party for people with the same first name, maybe. :)

Comment: @Pauli we keep loosing money because of programmers like me